# Way of making site responsive with something else than media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design

Let's just say that I'm really not a fan of responsive design (or creating it to be more specific), but I do understand it's necessary. Is there something that makes creating responsive design quicker and less annoying? My code usually ends up with two many media queries or something along those lines and after a while it's one big mess. I used a little bit of Tailwind during React course I'm taking and it felt way more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its possible. No doubt, media queries requires a lot of code. But yes we have a smarter method too: https://getbootstrap.com/
This is bootstrap framework by using it you can easily make your theme responsive. And even many templates are available of bootstrap which are totally free to use as site.
You can either download or if you'll add this link to your view file then it can work.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
```

Hope you find it helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I heard about bootstrap, but now I'm wondering if there a big difference in usage between it and tailwind?

Comment: Well, I personally use bootstrap & prefer it mostly. But you can easily use any one of them. Bootstrap is more convenient and compatible to use. But still both are good ways.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to improve more about styling a page is to use css frameworks.
Either [Tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/) or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) . Good luck mate!